# some page in my website didn't load doctype, so it display in quirks mode, can anyone help me?

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

here is my website: http://kidscare.edu.vn

When open it in IE9, the homepage switch to quirks mode and it display ugly

but when open another page, it will display fine http://kidscare.edu.vn/babiescare

I use <kbd>F12</kbd> tool to inspect, and I saw the doctype was not load in the header

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use <kbd>F12</kbd> tool (Firebug or IE's equivalent) to see if the doctype is loaded. These tools DO NOT show you the source, they show you how they inerpret the source.

To actually view the source, right click the screen and choose "View source".

The reason this displays in quirksmode I believe is because you are using the transitional doctype.

So try using the strict doctype instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it.
Do you have another suggestion for doctype to replace transitional?

Comment: I use the strict doctype which generally avoids the quirksmode issues. See my updated answer for the details. Note though that this might make your site layout quite differently in various browsers which will now be less forgiving of "illegal" HTML or CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it.
Actually some page load normally, some page display wrong.
I use wordpress for this website, with only 1 header file.
I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I would need more info as to which pages are ok and which are not. Also for which browser you are talking about.

Comment: This problem appears in IE9, and this is the page with error http://kidscare.edu.vn
and the page with normal view http://kidscare.edu.vn/babiescare